Angular Importing Sass File Does not Include its Styles
Running into a confusing issue. I have an angular component setup like this:
@Component({
  selector: '[my-tag]', // eslint-disable-line
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrl: './my-tag.component.scss',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

Then in the scss file i have:
@import '../../mixins';
@import  './_tag.scss';
@import  './_tag-extenstions.scss';

However when i do these imports it does not create the css on the component. It will only work if i actually put the contents of those two imports directly inside the my-tag.component.scss
I can tell sass is "compiling" because it is reading the mixins and not erroring if i have that import.
I just dont understand why:
a) it wont include the css when its an import?
b) secondary question: also ViewEncapsulation.Emulated and ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDOM also do not put any css in. Only none works?
What gives?
